# How to transfer an App Store app after developer enrolment ended?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect, developer-program

I want to transfer an app from iTunes Connect. App was previously approved for Apple and was on sale. Now my developer license has expired. And now I can not find `Transfer App` and even `Delete App` button. Is there a way to transfer an app in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it until you renew your developer account.

But, I know a couple of cases where calling Apple and explaining the case, Apple renew the account for 10 days to let users delete apps (don't know about transferring, but you could try).